# Converting SQL data into a QTextDocument and then outputting a pdf

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to add a way to export data from an sqlite3 database into a pdf document. In the book rapid gui programming with python and Qt it says that I can export QTextDocuments as pdf files. However it need to be in the form of a QTextDocument. At the moment I have been trying to get a string of headers for the table into a pdf document as a test however when it is run idle just restarts.

```
    import sqlite3
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
    class Report(QtWidgets.QWidget):
        def __init__(self,text):
            super(Report,self).__init__()
            self.textArea = QTextEdit(self)
            self.cursor = QTextCursor(self.textArea.document())
            self.cursor.insertText(text)

    def createTextReport(fileName):
        headings = ('|%10s|'%'AssetID' + '|%40s|'%'Description' + '|%40s|'%'Room Description' + '|%5s|'%'Labelled' + '|%10s|'%'Condition')
        report = Report(headings)
        printer = QPrinter()
        printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.Letter)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName('C:/Users/Luke/Documents/A-Level-Work/A2/Computing/COMP 4/Program/report.pdf')
        report.print_(printer)


    fileName = 'C:/Users/Luke/Documents/A-Level-Work/A2/Computing/COMP 4/Program/test_database.db'

    createTextReport(fileName)
```

I am wondering where i am going wrong and also is there a simple way of getting data from an SQL query into a QTextDocument format as a table so i don't have to format it manually. Please make explanations in simple terms as my programming knowledge is very limited.

Comment: Where is it going wrong? Does the code run? Do you need pointers on how to structure your data?

Comment: The code runs but idle restarts when it reaches createTextReport(fileName) without providing an error. I was wondering if there was some module that would convert SQL to QTextDocument.

Comment: Also in case somebody asks no file is created.

Comment: Since Qt is a rather tightly-coupled system, it's possible that you have to create a running `QApplication` before you can use some of its libraries. It's pretty dumb, but that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have tuples from your `sqlite3` module, then you can format your data using something like this:

```
myText = ''

for entry in conn.execute('SOME SQL QUERY'):
    myText += '|{:10s}| AssetID |{:40s}| Description |{:40s}| Room Description |{:5s}| Labelled |{:10s}| Condition'.format(*entry)
    myText += '\n'
```

Then you can feed this text into your `Report()` object.

Used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181927/new-style-formatting-with-tuple-as-argument).

Comment: Thanks for the help with SQL to text! Do you have any ideas on why the  text to pdf section of code wont work?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I've been a little busy lately.