# Using "try:" to write to a file not working

Tags: python

I'm playing around with try: and am expecting 'Hello' to be written to testfile.tx. However when I check the file, 'Hello' doesn't appear. What is wrong with my code?

```
try:
    f = open('testfile.txt', 'w')
    f.write('Hello')
except TypeError:
    print ('There was a type error')
except OSError:
    print('There was an OS error')
finally:
    print('I always run')
```

Comment: Works for me. Do you get any errors? Are you sure you're checking the right output file?

Comment: Use `finally: f.close()`

Comment: Maybe use `with open(...)` altogether.

Comment: But the buffer would be flushed anyway when the process exists and the OS cleans up the open file descriptors, wouldn't it? Guess this may depend on the file system and its internal caching...

Comment: The file will be created in the current directory.  It sounds like you're just looking in the wrong directory for the file (and the directory where you're looking might also have an empty file of the same name).  You can add this code to see the actual current directory `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Your edit completely changed the question. Please don't do that, especially if you've already received answers. But `foo.format(a, b)` and `foo.format((a, b))` are different things. See [New style formatting with tuple as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181927/new-style-formatting-with-tuple-as-argument). I'm rolling the question back to its original form.

Comment: @JorgeGandara, I understand that you're frustrated. But [there are good reasons for rate limiting and other restrictions on question asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/354577). Changing an old question is counterproductive for many reasons, not least of which that you aren't likely to get answers to the new question that way. In any case, profanity is not appropriate. Please read our [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: @Chris How is someone who doesn't know the proper terminology and is learning how to code supposed to ask "perfect questions"? I just know how to describe my issue. It seems like the only people allowed to ask questions are advanced coders. Makes no sense. There should be consideration for "dumb questions", not just complete shunning. How am I supposed to "fix my existing questions" if I don't even know proper coding terminology and am looking for help just TRYING to get started in coding.

Comment: @JorgeGandara, there's no requirement to be perfect. 'How am I supposed to "fix my existing questions" if I don't even know proper coding terminology'—I think you already know this from earlier comments but just in case: not by completely changing what you've asked. That invalidates existing answers. The idea is to _improve_ questions, not _overwrite_ them. The self-answer that you posted below has a comment on it that suggests one way to clarify what you were asking. Perhaps you could edit that into the question?

Answer (score 2):

I see you already fixed the problem by doing this:

```
try:
    f = open('testfile.txt', 'w')
    f.write('Hello')
except TypeError:
    print ('There was a type error')
except OSError:
    print('There was an OS error')
finally:
    f.close()
    print('I always run')
```

This is alright, and properly writes the data in the buffer. However, you're better off using a [context manager](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/).

This syntax is more concise, less mistake-prone, and automatically closes the file even if an error occurs:

```
with open('testfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Hello")
```

Comment: I agree, - I just wanted to be as consistent with what the poster had in their code as possible

Comment: Got it, I'll change the code

Answer (score 0):

I didn't close the file with f.close()

I added f.close() and it works now!

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Oh, so you were running this code inside of an IDE or shell, not as a separate script?  Mentioning that would have been helpful.